# Ruby 1.9.3 Is Not Installing (Mac OS X Lion)

Tags: ruby

Here's my current version of Ruby:

```
Matts-MacBook-Pro:~ cinicraft$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-12-28 patchlevel 357) [universal-darwin11.0]
```

So I want to upgrade to 1.9.3, this is what I'm trying:

```
Matts-MacBook-Pro:~ cinicraft$ rvm install 1.9.3

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.7/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p448.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/cinicraft/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p448 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p448, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p448 - #extracted to /Users/cinicraft/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p448 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p448 - #configuring........
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/cinicraft/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --disable-install-doc --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared',
please read /Users/cinicraft/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p448/1376080574_configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

What the phantom menace is this thing's problem?

Comment: What does the log say? That would be a good start.

Comment: provide the output of the log file cited in the error message

Comment: We can't help you unless you tell us what the specific error is in your log file. Without that we're just guessing and wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

Your RVM is out of date.

```
rvm get head
rvm install 1.9.3
```